# Flag is never initialized

Tags: java, initialization, boolean

I created a program to match two txt files. I get the compile error that flag is never initialized but I don't know why. The for loop should run and the if else should initialize flag. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    boolean flag;
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    File f2 = new File(args[1]);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(f2);
    int line = 1;
    String t1 = "";
    String t2 = "";

    while(sc.hasNextLine() && sc2.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line1 = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        String line2 = sc2.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        for(int i = 0; i < line; i++)
        {
            if(line1.substring(0,i).equals(line2.substring(0,i)))
            {
                flag = false;
                t1 = line1.substring(0,i);
                t2 = line2.substring(0,i);
                System.out.print("");
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
                t1 = line1.substring(0,i);
                t2 = line2.substring(0,i);
                System.out.print("");
            }
        }

        if(flag == true)
        {
            System.out.println("Line # " + line + ": Matching " + line + "character/s true" + "**" + t1 + "**" + t1 + "**");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Line # " + line + ": Matching " + line + "character/s false" + "**" + t1 + "**" + t2 + "**");
        }
        line += 1;
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: What if your `for` loop never runs? What is the value of `flag` then?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your main function, it complains because of this line:

```
boolean flag;
```

You need to initialize this variable. What is the default behavior? If the for loop never runs, what would/should the value be?

For example, what if you pass the function two empty files (or one empty file)?. Then, your while loop:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine() && sc2.hasNextLine())
```

Would be false, and the flag would never get set. That's why the compiler complains.